# Querying ALL test runs using QueryTestRuns()

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to query all test runs within a particular team project. The query works, but it only contains some of the results.  Below is the list of recent runs.  The ones for DEV are querying fine, but the ones for QA do not come through in the query.  Sadly, the QA ones are the only ones I'm interested in.

[TFS Run List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Cus.png)

Here is the code I currently have:

```
// Get the catalog of team project collections
CatalogNode catalogNode = configurationServer.CatalogNode;
ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> tpcNodes = catalogNode.QueryChildren(
    new Guid[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
    false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

CatalogNode teamProject = null;

// List the team project collections
foreach (CatalogNode tpcNode in tpcNodes)
{
    // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
    Guid tpcId = new Guid(tpcNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
    tpc = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcId);

    if (tpc.Name == TPC_NAME)
    {
        teamProject = tpcNode;
        break;
    }
}

if (teamProject == null)
    throw new Exception(string.Format(@"Missing team project collection '{0}'", TPC_NAME));

_testManagementService = tpc.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

// Get the test runs 
IEnumerable<ITestRun> testRuns = _testManagementService.QueryTestRuns(string.Format("select * From TestRun")).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCompleted);

foreach (var testRun in testRuns)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test run: '{0}'", testRun.Title);
}
```

This is using VS and TFS 2015.

So why do only some builds come through? Is there some other way of querying, or is there some sort of hidden filter I don't know about? I wanted to look at the TFS schema in case there's another table in there or something, but apparently that's impossible because Microsoft is vigilantly protecting us from ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot get the test runs for distributed testing with the client library API either. And I use the [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/runs#get-test-runs-by-query) to get them as an alternative way.

Comment: I've seen that suggestion in one or two other places, and it seems the only way to get around this that I can find currently.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It seems related to security considerations: “View test runs” is the **required permission to view all test objects. Without this permission, users will get no result back from a query.** Test objects bound to Area nodes are also subjected to Area node permission. For example, if user A does not have read permission to Area node X, the test objects in node X will not be returned as part of the query results.

Comment: My TFS admin assures me that I have all necessary privileges to do this...I'm currently wondering if this is because the QA builds are distributed, and when they were set up nobody apparently knew how to do the Publish Test Results step, so it was disabled.  I'm having a hard time finding an example of how that should be filled out too.